# Android TelephonyManager gives inconsistent results

Tags: android, xamarin, telephonymanager, imei

My app (written in Xamarin / C#) generates a device specific ID from the TelephonyManager. Below is a portion of my code for doing this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);

string tmDevice, tmSerial;
tmDevice = "" + tm.DeviceId;//IMEI
tmSerial = "" + tm.SimSerialNumber;
```

Most of the time I have no issues with this. However, on Conquest XWT5 / XWT5S devices this gives inconsistent results sometimes. Occasionally on these devices the DeviceId and SimSerialNumber return null, which makes the id inconsistent and causes problems. The devices in question run Android 4.0.4.
Has anyone seen this problem before - I have been unable to find anyone else who has seen this issue. I think this has happened on more than one of these devices so I don't think it is a glitch with just one device. The devices definitely have a phone component and SIM card present.
Thanks